# fullcalendar change columns to row

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

there is a way to change the display of fullcalendar to show the days (Sunday, Monday,...) in the vertical axis and the time in the horizontal axis, I have to show that way to my client.

Regards.-

Comment: I also would love to implement this.

Comment: You probably need to create your own view as it is not in the source now. (source code here: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar)

Comment: where were you 11 votes come from? you didn't say anything in your topic

Answer (score 1):

There is no designated way to do that. But you can do it yourself.

Fullcalendar view is shown as table with the following structure:

```
<tr class="fc-week0 fc-first" style="">
  <td class="fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-day0 fc-first fc-other-month">…</td>
  <td class="fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-day1 fc-other-month">…</td>
```

As you can see there is a row for each weak, and a cell for each day.

You have 2 options to accomplish what you want:

1. Modify the plugin source. The view is rendered in [BasicView.js](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/basic/BasicView.js). Just change the lines  140 and below and "substitute" td <-> tr.
2. Write some extra code to reorder the elements. Write a small and simple script which gets called as soon as the calendar is inserted into DOM. The script has to rebuild your table in the order you like.

Comment: your 1st option is not working for me..can u please help me in doing the 2nd option.. @k_wave

Answer (score 1):

Jarno Kurlin has forked a horizontal Fullcalendar view for resource management:

https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar

Based on this old link:
http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

It does not show time detail on the horizontal axis, but you may be able to more easily tweak this to get it to match your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `eventRender` method, and you can make FullCalendar events appear in almost any way you choose. The question [How to adjust width and position of events in jQuery Full Calendar in week-view and day view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237974/how-to-adjust-width-and-position-of-events-in-jquery-full-calendar-in-week-view) addressed a similar issue.

The `eventRender` method is described in their API here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

In case you need it, you can also use their `eventAfterRender` method: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/

```
var $yourCalendar = $('#calendarId');
$yourCalendar.fullCalendar({
   events[//your events
   ],
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    // Reposition your element here
   },
   eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
    // Make minor post-rendering corrections to your element here
   }
});
```