# Modify FullCalendar Javascript Plugin Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

As you can see the default layout of [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is like this
[image]

**I want to change it to be like this**
[image]

That Room Column is something that is custom or shall I say, it came from the database, that wouldn't be important for now since what I really wanted to know is how to achieve that kind of layout.

I honestly do not know where to start that's why I run here in SO. I've been looking some examples in the internet but can't find anything.

How would I start in doing that kind of layout? Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up. I managed to solved this one when doing some thorough research.
I found that someone already developed this kind of solution.
First I found this link here in SO: [fullcalendar change columns to row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272393/fullcalendar-change-columns-to-row)

Then upon reading the comments, it lead me to here http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

It just needs a little tweaking of course, but this would do.

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think that FullCalendar does not offer this flexibility by customizing it. You will find better solutions by extending or modifying the lib, but a solution without modifications may be:

1. Your 'relative view' should be a 'week view', then you will have your week days displayed (as you need).
2. Set the 'select function' to always set 'allDay' to 'true'. At this point you will have what you need, but just for one room/row.
3. Turn each room (row) into a new FullCalendar.
4. Modify the CSS (overwrite) as you need.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you very much for your tip. Just another question, what do you mean by "Set the 'select function' to always set 'allDay' to 'true'? I know that there's an 'allDay' params in the calendar which I already set it into 'true', the part that I did not understand is the 'select function', what's that? Thanks! :)

Comment: When initializing fullcalendar by calling $('#yourdiv').fullCalendar, you can specify many parameters as you did with 'allDay'.
One of them is the parameter 'select'. You can pass a function to this parameter that will be a callback, triggered when selecting/clicking on a day to create an event. Then you can manipulate your new event as you wish, e.g. setting it to allDay.